# Repeat events monthly, creates some problems

Tags: java, spring, calendar

I want to repeat events monthly. it is successful except days 29,30,31st.

```
calendar.setTime(previousOcuurance);
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
nextOcuurance = calendar.getTime();
```

in case the previous occurrence is jan 31st.the next occurrence is given by this code is feb 28th. but i need feb 31.

is there any way .. please help me

Comment: Just to make sure--you are aware that there is no such thing as February 31st, correct? the Calendar class implements a real-world Gregorian-style calendar with variable month lengths.

Comment: @mech  i know about, but i need it like that. is there any way

Comment: You're going to have to create your own Calendar sub-class, probably inheriting from the abstract java.util.Calendar class. The normal Calendar will not do what you need it to do.

Comment: Would you be fine if the invalid date 2016-02-31 will be mapped to 2016-03-02 (carry over of day overflow)?